# How to restrict Field Write access in Sitecore by roles

Tags: security, sitecore, sitecore7.5

Let's say I have a data template that has 3 field sections: Basic Info, Navigation Info and Content Info.  I would like to restrict Field Write access to the fields in these sections by role.  I know that it is fairly simple to create a role for each of these and deny Field Write for the other sections.  For example, I could create a role called Basic Info Editor Role and deny Field Write for all of the fields in the Navigation Info and Content Info sections.  However I need to have the ability for a given user to be a member of more than one role sometimes.  So I may have a user called jSmith that is a member of both the Basic Info Editor Role and also the Navigation Info Editor Role.  I want jSmith to be able to edit both of those sections of content.

I can't figure out how to do this.  It seems that by default all users have Field Write access to all templates.  I think somehow I need to remove inheritance so that they don't all have the Field Write granted or something.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I remember you cannot assign `Field Read` and `Field Write` access rights on the section level - you can only do this on the field items directly.

Anyway, I think your approach is correct:

- select chosen field which should be restricted
- break the inheritance of this field for your base role (e.g. `Standard Editor`)
- and then create `Basic Info Editor Role` which will be a member of the `Standard Editor` role
- add `Field Write` option for the selected field for `Basic Info Editor Role` role.

All other `Standard Editors` won't be able to change this field, only `Basic Info Editors` will be allowed to change it.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  This did work.  The mistake I was making was that I tried to break inheritance at the template level.  And that had no effect at all on the Field Read or Field Write permissions.  Once I broke inheritance at the individual field level it worked fine.